# Computing the Module of Kähler Differentials for a separably generated field extension $K/k$ (Vakil Exercise 21.2.M).

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

We say a field extension $K/k$ is *seperably generated* by $t_1, \dots, t_n$ if these elements form a transcendence basis, and $K/k(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ is algebraic and seperable. The ultimate goal is to show that $dt_i$ form a $K$-basis of $\Omega_{K/k}$.

First, I claim that $\Omega_{k(t_1, \dots, t_n)/k} = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n k(t_1, \dots, t_n) dt_i$. After all, $k(t_1, \dots, t_n) = S^{-1}k[t_1, \dots, t_n]$ for the multiplicative set $S$ of nonzero elements. Hence, since the module of differentials commutes with localization we have that $$\Omega_{k(t_1, \dots, t_n)/k} = k(t_1, \dots, t_n) \otimes_{k[t_1, \dots, t_n]} \Omega_{k[t_1, \dots, t_n]/k} = k(t_1, \dots, t_n) \otimes_{k[t_1, \dots, t_n]} \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n k[t_1, \dots, t_n]dt_i =  \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n k(t_1, \dots, t_n) dt_i.$$

Is this calculation correct?

Next, we apply the cotangent sequence to the maps $k \hookrightarrow k(t_1, \dots, t_n) \hookrightarrow K$ to get the exact sequence of $K$-modules $$K \otimes_{k(t_1, \dots, t_n)} \Omega_{k(t_1, \dots, t_n)/k} \to \Omega_{K/k} \to \Omega_{K/k(t_1, \dots, t_n)} \to 0.$$ Since $K/k(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ is separable and algebraic, $\Omega_{K/k(t_1, \dots, t_n)} = 0$ (by exercise 12.2.F) so the multiplication map $$K \otimes \Omega_{k(t_1, \dots, t_n)/k} \to \Omega_{K/k}$$ is surjective. Hence, $dt_i$ generate $\Omega_{K/k}$ as a $K$-vector space. To conclude, we must show they are linearly independent.

This is where I am stuck. My strategy is to define a $k$-derivation $d_i: K \to K$ so that $d_i(t_j) = \delta_{ij}$ so that by the universal property of $\Omega_{K/k}$, if $\sum f_i dt_i =0$, then $f_i = 0$. I am having trouble finding this map, though. My guess is to somehow extend $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t_i}: k(t_1, \dots, t_n) \to k(t_1, \dotsm t_n)$$ to $K$. I thought that we could just apply the functor $- \otimes K$ to get a map $K \to K$, but this seems to kill the map instead. Could I have any hints or suggestions as to how I can find this derivation or even extend $\partial/\partial t_i$ in a nice way?

Comment: First: the calculation you ask about is correct. Next, derivations have a tricky relation with linear algebra, so of course you can’t just extend the scalars. Instead, you need to define $\partial x/\partial t_i$ for a primitive element of $K/k(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ – for the extended derivation to be well-defined, the only condition is that said extension vanishes at the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $k(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$. That gives you a value for $\partial x/\partial t_i$.

Comment: @Mindlack What does it mean for an element to be primitive in an infinite field extension? $K/k(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ can be infinite, right?

Comment: Ah. Oops. Well, the argument shows that you have an isomorphism for all finite subextensions of $K$ and then you can probably “go to the limit”.

Comment: @Mindlack Perhaps I should just do this, since differentials and tensor products behave well with limits. This is how Eisenbud proves an analogous result in his commutative algebra book.